# Reading xml nodes into array and getting max value vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This is a V6 File.-->
<ROOT>
  <EVENT>
    <APPOINT.APPNO>123456</APPOINT.APPNO>
    <APPOINT.DATE>01/01/2021</APPOINT.DATE>
    <PERSON_INFO>
      <PERSON.CUSTNO>12131415</PERSON.CUSTNO>
      <PERSON.LAST>WAYNE</PERSON.LAST>
      <PERSON.FIRST>BRUCE</PERSON.FIRST>
      <PERSON.MI />
      <PERSON.STREET>1234 RANDOM ST</PERSON.STREET>
      <PERSON.APT />
      <PERSON.CITY>GOTHAM</PERSON.CITY>
    </PERSON_INFO>
    <ACCOUNT_INFO>
      <CARRIER_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY>
        <ITEM.GROUP>PERSON GROUP</ITEM.GROUP>
        <ITEM.SUM_CHRG>100.50</ITEM.SUM_CHRG>
        <ITEM.SUM_PAID>0</ITEM.SUM_PAID>
        <ITEM.SUM_WOFF>0</ITEM.SUM_WOFF>
        <ITEM.SUM_XOVR>0</ITEM.SUM_XOVR>
        <ITEM.SUM_DEDUCTIBLE>0</ITEM.SUM_DEDUCTIBLE>
        <ITEM.SUM_DUE>100.50</ITEM.SUM_DUE>
      </CARRIER_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY>
      <CARRIER_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY>
        <ITEM.GROUP>PERSON GROUP #2</ITEM.GROUP>
        <ITEM.SUM_CHRG>225.50</ITEM.SUM_CHRG>
        <ITEM.SUM_PAID>110.50</ITEM.SUM_PAID>
        <ITEM.SUM_WOFF>0</ITEM.SUM_WOFF>
        <ITEM.SUM_XOVR>115.00</ITEM.SUM_XOVR>
        <ITEM.SUM_DEDUCTIBLE>0</ITEM.SUM_DEDUCTIBLE>
        <ITEM.SUM_DUE>0.00</ITEM.SUM_DUE>
      </CARRIER_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY>
      <ITEM>
        <ITEM.TRCNO>654321</ITEM.TRCNO>
        <ITEM.INVOICE>987654</ITEM.INVOICE>
      </ITEM>
    </ACCOUNT_INFO>
    <DETAIL_INFO>
      <DETAIL>
        <TOADD.TOANO>123456</TOADD.TOANO>
        <TOADD.EPCRNUM>00-00-000000</TOADD.EPCRNUM>
      </DETAIL>
    </DETAIL_INFO>
  </EVENT>
</ROOT>
```

I'm getting the nodes I need using this:

```
Dim xnlNodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ROOT/EVENT")
```

I'm trying to get the `<ITEM.SUM_CHRG>` into an array, so for `person.custno`'12131415' there would be a value of "100.50", and a value of "225.50" in the array, and I want to use a max method to determine which is the largest value in the array.

I am struggling with just creating the array because I honestly just struggle with arrays in vb.net. I've tried doing a loop, checking the child node names for "ITEM.SUM_CHRG" And putting the value into a variable called strSumChrg so I can check if it's larger that way but I think I'm way off.

I am doing the above inside a for each loop like below

```
xmlDoc.Load(strFileName)
Dim xnlNodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ROOT/EVENT")
  For Each xnNode As XmlNode In xnlNodes

        Dim strSumChrg As Decimal = 0
        If xnSC.Name = "ITEM.SUM_CHRG" Then
            If xnSC.FirstChild.Value > 0 Then
                strSumChrg = Math.Max(CDec(xnSC.FirstChild.Value), strSumChrg)
            End If
        End If

Next
```

Comment: While dealing with XML it is better to use **LINQ to XML**. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Comment: I will research that thank you. So it will be easier for me to accomplish what I'm looking to do with Linq specifically is what you are saying correct?

Comment: The provided XML is not well-formed. Please edit your question, and fix it.

Comment: fixed, it's exactly like the file I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using LINQ to XML. No loops.

I had to fix the XML file to make it well-formed.

The following tag is not matching in the XML sample.

```
<ITEM.GROUP>PERSON GROUP</ITEM.GROUP_CARRIER>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub Main()
    Const fileName As String = "e:\Temp\shadow2020.xml"

    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    Dim maxValue = doc.Descendants("ITEM.SUM_CHRG").Max(Function(x) CDec(x))
    Console.WriteLine(maxValue)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
225.50
```

Comment: 'Descendants' is not a member of 'XmlDocument'. I have `Imports System.Linq`, what else do I need?

Comment: `Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: If I do System.Xml.Linq, my error list shows me: "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Xml.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found' Do I have to install from the nuget manager? - installed from nuget manager, and that allowed me to do the import

Comment: I still get "Descendants' is not a member of 'XmlDocument'"

Comment: It is `XDocument` not the `XmlDocument.` I gave you a working code. Even its output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlSerialization. Create some classes which represent your data

```vb
<XmlRoot("ROOT")>
Public Class Root
    <XmlElement("EVENT")>
    Public Property Events As List(Of [Event])
End Class
Public Class [Event]
    <XmlElement("APPOINT.APPNO")>
    Public Property AppointAppNo As Integer
    <XmlElement("APPOINT.DATE")>
    Public Property AppointDateString As String
    <XmlIgnore>
    Public ReadOnly Property AppointDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return DateTime.ParseExact(AppointDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
        End Get
    End Property
    <XmlElement("PERSON_INFO")>
    Public Property PersonInfo As PersonInfo
    <XmlElement("ACCOUNT_INFO")>
    Public Property AccountInfo As AccountInfo
    <XmlElement("DETAIL_INFO")>
    Public Property DetailInfo As DetailInfo
End Class
Public Class PersonInfo
    <XmlElement("PERSON.CUSTNO")>
    Public Property CustNo As Integer
    <XmlElement("PERSON.LAST")>
    Public Property Last As String
    <XmlElement("PERSON.FIRST")>
    Public Property First As String
    <XmlElement("PERSON.MI")>
    Public Property MI As String
    <XmlElement("PERSON.STREET")>
    Public Property Street As String
    <XmlElement("PERSON.APT")>
    Public Property Apt As String
    <XmlElement("PERSON.CITY")>
    Public Property City As String
End Class
Public Class AccountInfo
    <XmlElement("CARRIER_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY")>
    Public Property Summaries As List(Of Summary)
    <XmlElement("ITEM")>
    Public Property Item As Item
End Class
Public Class DetailInfo
    <XmlElement("DETAIL")>
    Public Property Detail As Detail
End Class
Public Class Summary
    <XmlElement("ITEM.GROUP")>
    Public Property Group As String
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_CHRG")>
    Public Property SumCharge As Decimal
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_PAID")>
    Public Property SumPaid As Decimal
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_WOFF")>
    Public Property SumWoff As Decimal
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_XOVR")>
    Public Property SumXovr As Decimal
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_DEDUCTIBLE")>
    Public Property SumDeductible As Decimal
    <XmlElement("ITEM.SUM_DUE")>
    Public Property SumDue As Decimal
End Class
Public Class Item
    <XmlElement("ITEM.TRCNO")>
    Public Property ItemTrcNo As Integer
    <XmlElement("ITEM.INVOICE")>
    Public Property ItemInvoice As Integer
End Class
Public Class Detail
    <XmlElement("TOADD.TOANO")>
    Public Property ToAddToANo As Integer
    <XmlElement("TOADD.EPCRNUM")>
    Public Property ToAddEpcrNum As String
End Class
```

Then you can deserialize the file into .NET objects which have strong types and you can iterate using LINQ.

```vb
Dim myRoot As Root
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Root))
Using sr As New StreamReader("list.xml")
    myObject = serializer.Deserialize(sr)
End Using

Dim charges = myRoot.Events.
    Where(Function(e) e.PersonInfo.CustNo = 12131415).
    SelectMany(Function(e) e.AccountInfo.Summaries).
    Select(Function(s) s.SumCharge)

Console.WriteLine("Charges:")
For Each charge In charges
    Console.WriteLine(charge)
Next
Console.WriteLine($"Max: {charges.Max()}")
```

> Charges:
>
>  100.50
>
>  225.50
>
>  Max: 225.50

and of course can do *a lot of other things* once you have your data in proper .NET objects.